# How do I use low level FEM?

Tags: finite-element-method

How do I simulate the following partial differential equation using Low level FEM in Mathematica?

```
D[u[x,y], x] - D[u[x,y], y] = x Sin[x y] - y Sin[x y]
```

The answer is Cos[x y]

added)

The region is [-1,1] for x and [-1,1] for y.

The boundary condition is u[-1,y]=Cos[-y]

Comment: In what sense is this a differential equation? Normally you are looking for an unknown function that is defined through  a differential equation. What is the unknown function?

Comment: my code was wrong.at first,I did used Cos(xy) for creating PDE and solve by FEM. the unknown function is u[x,y]

Comment: Do you have  a region on which you wish to solve the equation and boundary conditions?

Comment: region is {x,-1,1} and{y,-1,1}. Boundary Condition is u[-1,y]=Cos[-y]

Comment: Can you specify what problem you encountered? Otherwise there is an entire tutorial on [FiniteElementProgramming](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html).

Comment: Also note that this specific equation is convection dominated and most likely will not give good results with the FEM. Are you tied to this specific equation?

Comment: 1. I first read the tutorial, but it was a bit abstract to understand what the FEM itself is doing for me.

My problem is that I do not know how to convert any PDE to solve it with FEM.
I can not understand the flow of bringing it to the matrix form after making the mesh or how to make the mesh.


2. There is no particular reason to be concerned about this equation. It is okay with something like diffusion equations.

Comment: For example, if you have a two-dimensional PDE, you can solve it by bringing it into a recursive expression with FDM.

However, in  3 or 4 dimensional problem it feels a bit difficult.
So I began studying FEM, but I 'm stacked for more than a week.
I will attach the FEM code I tried.

Comment: I need to understand a bit better what you want to do. What is the purpose of this? Do you need the matrices? What is your end goal? If you want to plot the solution using `NDSolve` is enough, or not?

Comment: My goal is to solve PDE with FEM other than NDSolve.

I mentioned Matrix because of some example of FEM used Matrix Form.

NDSolve is very useful, but it seems not to be able to deal with my problem. So I have to build my own solver with FEM

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not a 100% sure I understand your question, here is what I think could help you.

The finite element method is, strictly speaking, not a method to solve PDEs. What it does it takes a continuous PDE and converts it to an approximate equivalent matrix and vector. The matrix and vector are discrete representations of the PDE. When you solve this set of equations you will get an approximate solution to the PDE.

We set up an equation:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];
```

Now we extract some data from the NDSolve state data object.

```
femdata = state["FiniteElementData"]
femdata["Properties"]
methodData = femdata["FEMMethodData"];
bcData = femdata["BoundaryConditionData"];
pdeData = femdata["PDECoefficientData"];
variableData = state["VariableData"];
solutionData = state["SolutionData"][[1]];
```

If you do not want to / can not use NDSolve`ProcessEquations you may need to look at `InitializePDECoefficients` and such functions.

If you look at pdeData, that now contains the coefficients of the equations given in NDSolve:

```
pdeData["All"]

{{{{1}}, {{{{0}, {0}}}}}, {{{{{-1, 
      0}, {0, -1}}}}, {{{{0}, {0}}}}, {{{{0, 
      0}}}}, {{0}}}, {{{0}}}, {{{0}}}}
```

Now, the finite element method is applied. This converts the continuous PDE into a system of discrete matrices:

```
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[pdeData, methodData, solutionData]
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = discretePDE["SystemMatrices"]
```

You can look at the matrices:

```
MatrixPlot[stiffness]
```

The same conversion is done for the boundary conditions:

```
discreteBCs = 
  DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcData, methodData, solutionData];
```

All the finite element method does is done now. The rest is linear algebra.

We now put the discrete boundary conditions into the discrete matrices:

```
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, discreteBCs]
```

Solve:

```
solution = LinearSolve[stiffness, load];
```

Generate an Interpolating function:

```
mesh = methodData["ElementMesh"];
ifun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, solution]
```

And visualize:

```
Plot3D[ifun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

Also, there is a tutorial about [Finite Element Programming](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) that has much more information on this topic.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: How can I customize/change mesh data using this method?

Comment: @Diogo, you could use for example: `{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, Element[{x,y}, myMesh]]`